# Whether we can update existing model in spark-ml/spark-mllib?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

We are using spark-ml to build the model from existing data. New data comes on daily basis.

Is there a way that we can only read the new data and update the existing model without having to read all the data and retrain every time?

Comment: Hi Jeffery is there a way to connect with u , I also looking for a similar solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the model you're using but for some Spark does exactly what you [want](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#mllib-operations). You can look at [StreamingKMeans](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.StreamingKMeans), [StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD), [StreamingLogisticRegressionWithSGD](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.StreamingLogisticRegressionWithSGD) and more broadly [StreamingLinearAlgorithm](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.StreamingLinearAlgorithm).

Answer (score 2):

To complete Florent's answer, if you are not in a streaming context, some Spark mllib models support an `initialModel` as a starting point for incremental updates. See [KMeans](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans), or [GMM](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.GaussianMixture) for instance.